# POST request using Power Query

Tags: rest, powerquery, m

I'm trying to collect data from the major electronic components distributors using their API with Power Query.

I was able to do it easily with ARROW and FARNELL as they use a GET request but now I'm trying to do the same thing with MOUSER but it's a POST request.

Here's the code I've written so far but it's not working :

##### edit

Can someone please help me and tell me what's wrong ?

The API documentation is here:

https://api.mouser.com/api/docs/ui/index#/SearchApi/SearchApi_SearchByPartNumber

Thanks for your help !

##### edit

My first attempt was really awful, I've made a few changes but it's still not working:

```fs
let
    url = "https://api.mouser.com/api/v1.0/search/partnumber?apiKey=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    body = Json.FromValue({[SearchByPartRequest = ""], [mouserPartNumber = "LL4148"], [partSearchOptions = "3"]}),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content- 
    Type"="application/json"], Content = body]))
in
    Source
```

##### edit

I get the following error:

[error message (from Power Query or the API ?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjobn.jpg)

Comment: Could you improve the formatting on your question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is in the [`Web.Contents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents) function.

You can read more information [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/API-Calls/m-p/373230), [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/power-bi-report-generation-through-web), and [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-rest-apis-from-power-bi-power-query/).